# How to update the values of a dictionary with a condition?

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

Supposing I have a dictionary,

```
 {'A1':[3, 2, 1],
 'A2': [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
 'B1': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 'B2': [15]}
```

If I choose a number say 9, I want to update the values of all other keys, except A2 (since 9 belongs to key A2), with 'After' + the last element of the key where the value was found, in this case 14.

EDIT:
Another condition, when parsing through the dictionary if a given value is smaller than 9 we do not change its value.

Final dictionary,

```
 {'A1':[3, 2, 1],
 'A2': [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
 'B1': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 'B2': ['After 14']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your dictionary is `dct`, try a dictionary comprhension:

```
x = next(v[-1] for k, v in dct.items() if 9 in v)
>>> {k: v if (9 in v) or all(x < 9 for x in v) else [f'After {x}'] for k, v in dct.items()}
```

---

```
{'A1': [3, 2, 1], 'A2': [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 
 'B1': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'B2': ['After 14']}
```

Note this works for any value, not just `14`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just realized there's another condition which I forgot to add. Please see the edited question.

Comment: @royalewithcheese Edited my answer with working code

Comment: @royalewithcheese Check out my edit :)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, assuming mutually exclusive values (i.e. values do not overlap):

```
n = 9
key, (*_, last)  = next((k, v) for k, v in d.items() if n in v)

{k: [f"After {last}"] if k != key else v for k, v in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'A1': ['After 14'],
 'A2': [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
 'B1': ['After 14'],
 'B2': ['After 14']}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just realized there's another condition which I forgot to add. Please see the edited question. 
Note: Yes, the values do not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

If the dictionary is defined as `d`, then

```
d['A1'] = item
```

will change the item assigned at `'A1'`.

If you want automated algorithm then you can use:

```
for key in d:
    d[key] = item
```